# How can I set the Android Studio Structure Panel to reflect the actual order of the methods in the project

Tags: android, android-studio

In the structure Panel the methods can be sorted alphabetically or by visibility 
I'd like to be able to have the structure panel represent the order in which they appear in the actual code. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "unclick" the 'AZ' icon, the methods will not be sorted, they are represented the order in which they appear in your code.